# If mysql fulltext is involved, do any other indexes count?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a four column table - PK over the first three columns, and fulltext indexes over the last two columns (1 index each).

My query is

```
SELECT s.* FROM table1 s WHERE MATCH (s.col4) AGAINST ('+monkey* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND s.col1 = 2 AND s.col2 = 9
```

EXPLAIN tells me the key choices are Primary or fulltext, and it uses the fulltext one, which makes sense.

I'm wondering, should I pay and attention to the query's order ie, would it make a speed difference if it's...?

```
SELECT s.* FROM table1 s WHERE s.col1 = 2 AND s.col2 = 9 AND MATCH (s.col4) AGAINST ('+monkey* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

To give you an idea of the data - there might be up to 200 000 instances of col1 / col2 combinations eg there might be 200 000 x (col1 = 999, col2 = 88), but only about 10 instances of 'monkey' within those 200 000 rows, 10 instances of monkey in another 200 000 combo (col1 = 77, col2 = 9995) etc

I understand MySQL isn't great for fulltext, but I need to use it temporarily while getting solr up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of the `WHERE` clause has no impact on selection of indexes as long as reordering the terms of the where clause does not change the logical expression that it represents.

With very few exceptions, only one index can be used for any given query, with the remaining conditions being evaluated "Using where" (in the `Extra` column of `EXPLAIN`) by filtering out rows returned from the selected index to eliminate rows not otherwise matching the `WHERE` clause.

But selection of the index is independent of ordering of transposable terms in the `WHERE` clause.

Fulltext is an interesting case, though.

MySQL's optimizer is cost-based, and as I have [described previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949633/compound-fulltext-index-in-mysql/18950380#18950380), when you have a `FULLTEXT` index and one or more other non-fulltext indexes that are all otherwise also viable in the query, and the query is based only on `AND` (not `OR`) conditions, then the MySQL optimizer will tend to select the non-fulltext index if the non-fulltext index dive indicates that exactly 0 or 1 rows will match... and otherwise it will tend to go with a search of the `FULLTEXT` index.

Since the number of monkeys is immaterial if no '2' is found in col1, the optimizer is very likely to use the col1 index for that particular query since it can return an empty set very expeditiously and otherwise the fulltext search is assumed to be the more optimal path.

Declare the appropriate indexes on everything you'll use in the `WHERE` clause, but pay no attention to the ordering of "this" `AND` "that" `AND` "these" in the where clause, since they do not matter.  The optimizer will try to sort it out to the best of its ability, constrained by the fact that fulltext indexes do not return meaningful index stats to the optimizer -- but when it comes to cost estimates, they appear to win out unless another index can narrow the result down to 1 matched row or less (i.e. zero rows).

Let me know if you find results that aren't consistent with this analysis.

Comment: Cheers Michael. I'm learning something new from your reply each time I read it!

Comment: If only had written it more clearly in the first place, you could have learned it all the first time you read it. :)