# Simplest way to find my external ip address and port

Tags: ip, port, p2p

I'm trying to develop an applicaton for p2p communication between two android devices. In order to punch a hole through my NAT(s), I'd need to know my external ip address and port.

To that end, I've developed a java server on GAE to report my "remote" ip address and port. The problem is that on GAE I can get my ip address, but not my port. Without it, I'm unable to successfully punch the hole.

So, my question is what's the best, free method to find out my external IP address and port?

Comment: This would be for TCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a question that has no answer with TCP.

Here's the problem: your "port" is not a fixed value.  You don't have "an" external port.  You typically get one dynamically assigned for each outbound connection.

As answers you should see from the [test sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949633/compound-fulltext-index-in-mysql/18950380#18950380) posted in another answer clearly indicate, it's a moving target (though it may stay stationary for a short time due to the browser using HTTP/1.1 keepalives and actually reusing the same connection, not just the same port)... but if you hit the site repeatedly, you'll see it either drift around randomly, or increment.  Trying it from two different web browsers on the same machine, you'd never see the same port number -- the port corresponds to the specific source connection, not the machine sourcing the connection.

Sometimes, you may find that it's the same port number as the port your machine's stack opened for the outbound connection, but even when it is, it doesn't matter, because no traffic should be able to return to your machine on that port unless it is from the IP address and port of the machine to which you made the outbound connection.  Any decent network address translating device would never accept traffic from another source IP address and/or port, other than the one you addressed in the outbound connection.

There is no standard, simple, predictable, reliable, or consistent way to punch a hole in TCP NAT and then exploit that hole for a peer-to-per connection.  To the extent that such things are possible in a given NAT implementation, that is an implementation that is shoddy, broken, defective, and insecure.

See also: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5128

Comment: Is the test sites link wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your app could use a [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) server to get its external address.