# How to improve MYSQL full text search index with other column in the table?

Tags: full-text-search

I have this slow query (26 seconds):

`SELECT uniqueIDS FROM search_V2 WHERE siteID=1 AND status=1 AND (MATCH(data) AGAINST ('scale' IN BOOLEAN MODE));`

I like first the query work on **siteID_status** index and then work with the full search index.

Any solution for that?

Comment: Does your query use all indexes? This would be `INDEX siteID_status (siteID, status)` and `FULLTEXT indexname  (data)`. Check out with EXPLAIN.

Comment: @Christoph  no, only this one FULLTEXT index. It will be great if it will first use **siteID_status** and then the FULLTEXT index. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Noamway If the search queries are used multiple times, work with optimized views, possibly the query could also be optimized with a temporary table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is the best solution I found:

```
SELECT uniqueIDS FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM search_V2 WHERE siteID=1 AND status=1
) A
WHERE MATCH(data) AGAINST ('scale' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This post really help me: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15214/why-is-like-more-than-4x-faster-than-match-against-on-a-fulltext-index-in-mysq/15218#15218?newreg=36837d8616984e289377475b27ee0758

I hope it will help someone else also.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18949633/compound-fulltext-index-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the query which index to follow first. See Index hints at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-hints.html. Without testing it your query would be something like

`SELECT uniqueIDS FROM search_V2 WHERE siteID=1 AND status=1 AND (MATCH(data) AGAINST ('scale' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) USE INDEX(siteID_status,fulltext_index);`

with `fulltext_index` being the name of your fulltext index. Hope it works, but you are close.

Comment: That didn't help me. He still use only one index. Maybe because one of the index is full search. Anyway I found better solution to my problem